# How to set Anti Aliasing in Blackberry Storm?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, blackberry, blackberry-storm, rim-4.7

I m drawing in a bitmap like..

```
bitmap[i] = new Bitmap(60, 60);  
Graphics g = new Graphics(bitmap[i]);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawLine(....);
```

Now how to set Anti-Aliasing on before g.drawLine()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For antialiasing mode use [public void setDrawingStyle(int drawStyle, boolean on)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#setDrawingStyle(int,%20boolean))

For lines use

```
graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_AALINES, true);
graphics.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_AALINES, false);
```

For poligons use

```
graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_AAPOLYGONS, true);
graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_AAPOLYGONS, false);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I cant see its effect in Simulator. I will test it on Storm.

Comment: The flag `DRAWSTYLE_AAPOLYGONS` also applies to circles and ellipses. Its effect is perceptible in simulators, but you'll probably need to increase zoom to 4x.